# Displaying images from subdomain in root directory (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cross-domain, subdomain

I have a domain e.g. `example.com` and a subdomain `manage.example.com`. When adding news on the management site, I save the pictures in the `Image` folder located in the `manage.example.com` subdomain.

I am trying to use these images in the views of the root site (`example.com`) using `img` tags. I gave the full path `example.com/subdomains/manage/image/imagename.jpg` but nothing is shown. The path is apparently invalid but this is the path I get when I connect via FTP.

How can I display those pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path used by FTP (which might be expected to correspond to a path on the server's disk) is not necessary the same as the path which is accessible via the web. The two things do not have to correlate at all - a webserver can be configured to present a totally different picture to what is logically there on the disk.

If you're displaying the images on a webpage then you need to use the URL of each image in your HTML, just the same as if you had browsed directly to it. If it's a subdomain as you described then it's more likely going to be something along the lines of

```
<img src="http://manage.example.com/image/imagename.jpg"/>
```

But you'll need to check your webserver's config to see how the subdomain is set up and where the root folder of it is set to.

Comment: Oh I see, I was using the ftp path which is incorrect. I solved it by downloading the image on the server then using it, but I will switch to your solution. Thanks

Comment: No problem. The reason you must do it this way is because the browser receives your Html, containing the address of the image. It then has to make a separate HTTP request to the server to actually fetch the image file itself and display it. Therefore the path you give to the browser in the src must be a valid URL, not a path on disk. The browser cannot see the disk, it can only contact the webserver and request the content of a URL. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Yeah it is really clear, I can now proceed knowing what is actually going on. If I were to request the picture myself in the server side code and use it, will I get the same result? You are quite good at explaining btw

Comment: You _could_ do that, but almost nobody ever does. Because you then have to encode it as text (using base64) and insert that text into the HTML. HTML is text-only, it is usually the browser which does the work of embedding images, videos etc based on the links given within the HTML. So yeah your suggestion is theoretically possible but it's likely to be very inefficient in terms of the performance of your site, and it's more complicated to implement, which is why you'll almost never see a webpage working like that.